# Proving any directional derivative exists at (0,0)

Tags: real-analysis

My function is $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{|y|}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } y\neq 0\\
0 & \text{if } y=0.
\end{cases}.$$

I have to show that for every $\vec r \in \mathbb R^2$, the directional derivative $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{r}}(0,0) \qquad \text{exists}.$$

Here's what I've done:

Let $\vec{r}\in \mathbb R^2$ be of norm 1. If $\vec{r} = (1,0)$ or $(-1,0),$ then clearly 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{r}}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = 0.$$
 Otherwise, let $\vec{r} = (x_0,y_0).$ Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{r}}(0,0) &= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+tx_0, 0 +ty_0) - f(0,0)}{t}\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{tx_0}{|ty_0|}\sqrt{(tx_0)^2+(ty_0)^2} -0}{t}\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{t}{|t|}\cdot \frac{x_0}{|y_0|}\cdot t \| r\|}{t}\\
&= \frac{x_0}{|y_0|}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{|t|}
\end{align*}

But that limit does not exist. And now I'm starting to question whether or not the original statement is true. The absolute value is just messing with me, and I'm just not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\sqrt{t^2}=\vert t\vert$.

Comment: Very good hint +1. The OP's mistake is in the last part, from line 2 to line 3.